# Request wsdl from PHP

Tags: php, wsdl

Here is my WSDL

http://validator5.addressdoctor.com/webservice5/v1/addressvalidation.asmx?WSDL

I want to write PHP code to request this WSDL. Here is my code. And it returns address not supplied.

```
define("ADDRESSDOCTOR_WSDL_URL","http://validator5.addressdoctor.com/webservice5/v1/addressvalidation.asmx?WSDL");
define("ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_LOGIN","***");
define("ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_PASSWORD","****");
$parameters = array(
    "FormatType"=>"WITH_ORGANIZATION",
    "FormatDelimiter"=>"TAB",
    "CountryType"=>"NAME_EN",
    "CountryOfOrigin"=>"OFF",
    "StreetWithHNo"=>true,
    "FormatWithCountry"=>false,
    "ElementAbbreviation"=>"OFF",
    "PreferredScript"=>"LATIN_1",
    "PreferredLanguage"=>"ENGLISH",
    "StreetWithNumber"=>false,
    "GlobalMaxLength"=>0,
    "MaxResultCount"=>20,
    "GlobalCasing"=>"UPPER",
    "StandardizeInvalidAddresses"=>"OFF",
    "FlexibleRangeExpansion"=>"ON",
    "ProcessMode"=>"BATCH",
    "MatchingScope"=>"ALL"
);

$address_element = array(
    "RecordID"=>"REC_1245887",
    "DeliveryAddressLines"=>"250 East Marshall Street",
    "Locality"=>"Richmond",
    "PostalCode"=>"23219",
    "Province"=>"Virginia",
    "Country"=>"USA");

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($address_element);$i++):
$client = new SoapClient(ADDRESSDOCTOR_WSDL_URL);

    $function = $client->Process(array("login"=>ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_LOGIN,"password"=>ADDRESSDOCTOR_USER_PASSWORD,"parameters"=>array("ProcessMode"=>"BATCH","ValidationParameters"=>$parameters),"addresses"=>$address_element[$i]));
print_r(get_object_vars($function));
endfor;
```

Returns:
Array ( [ProcessResult] => stdClass Object ( [StatusCode] => 300 [StatusMessage] => 
addresses must be supplied ) )

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually attempt the work instead of having Stack do it for you.

1. Enable PHPs soap module within php.ini or verify its already enabled with phpinfo()
2. Write a script that creates the soap client from the wsdl.
3. Use the soap client's getFunctions to verify you can call the methods you mention in your post.

Once you get past all of this, you will be "help-able"

Comment: i already did and here am i upto. Please help me to move futher

Comment: I think it might be the way your iterating over the addresses array.  I think you may want to pass it in without that loop, and send it in as the entire array.  I would need creds to play around with the service to confirm though ;)

Comment: How can I send you the credit. But I want to send a batch process to send multiple address in one request.

Comment: I am basically trying to understand the request structure. From Process (addresses->ArrayOfAddress->Address->(all address input parameters like street,locality,deliveryAddressLine...)

Comment: For demystifying soap services, I use soapUI.  I suggest you install it and create a project from the address doctor wsdl.  Make sure you have the create mock requests checkbox selected.  Then you can view the xml that the service requires for its methods.  I think this will help you form the php to craft the xml properly.